# Mysql: How to find out the nth delivery for every customer between the date range

Tags: mysql

Requirement includes finding out customers who had 5th delivery in the specific date range

My data looks following way:

```
|ID|customer|sale_date  | amount|
=================================
|1  | 10   |   2021-02-09   |100|
|2  | 10   |   2021-02-10   |100|
|3  | 10   |   2021-02-11   |100|
|4  | 10   |   2021-02-12   |100|
|5  | 10   |   2021-02-13   |100|
|6  | 10   |   2021-02-14   |100|
|7  | 10   |   2021-02-15   |100|
|8  | 12   |   2021-02-09   |100|
|9  | 12   |   2021-02-10   |100|
|10 | 12   |   2021-02-11   |100|
|11 | 12   |   2021-02-12   |100|
|12 | 12   |   2021-02-13   |100|
|13 | 12   |   2021-02-14   |100|
|14 | 12   |   2021-02-15   |100|
|15 | 12   |   2021-02-16   |100|
|16 | 15   |   2021-02-04   |100|
|17 | 15   |   2021-02-06   |100|
|18 | 15   |   2021-02-10   |100|
```

what i am expecting:

```
| ID| customer| sale_date | amount|
=====================================
|1   |10   |   2021-02-13 |100|
|2   |12   |   2021-02-13 |100|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY sale_date) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, customer, sale_date, amount
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 5 AND sale_date >= '2021-02-01' AND sale_date < '2021-02-16;
```

Comment: Hi @Tim how can i add the date range in this following query where i want check the 5th delivery happend between 1 and 15 February 2021

Comment: the problem is its counting the number of deliveries between the range, what i need is if suppose the customer has 4th delivery on January  31 and his 5th delivery falls on or after 1 February  2021, i should fetch that particular customer.

Comment: In that case, I recant my earlier comment, the restriction on the sale date belongs then in the outer query, q.v. above.